# Rhodes or Titanium for Rails app in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ruby, titanium, rhodes

Hi i wanted to develop an iphone app with Ruby..
Is Rhodes or Titanium the best option?
i need to integrate GPS and google maps

Answer (score 2):

Rhodes is the only way to actually write a mobile app in Ruby.    It is not possible to do so with Titanium or any other framework.  Rhodes (and PhoneGap for that matter) emphasize writing interfaces with HTML5 and styling libraries like jQuery Mobile and Sencha Touch (but still to build a native app NOT a web app).   Titanium creates its own UI abstractions and does not allow use of such styling libraries.  We believe that use of HTML5

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write the iPhone app in Ruby then Rhodes is as far as I know your only choice. I've made several apps with Titanium and the only language(s) you can use is Javascript/Coffeescript (Coffeescript compiles to JS). Titanium's Ruby support is only for desktop as someone has already pointed out.

As far as capabilities for Rhodes check out http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps. Looks like they have support for Geolocation and Native maps.

Answer (score 1):

Rhodes seems to be a Ruby only solution, while Titanium offers support for Ruby/Python/PHP. Because of this, I would choose Rhodes. Other than that, you should have access to all of the features from all the frameworks.

Comment: Hi,i heard Titanium is more native thane Rhodes

Comment: Perhaps their book could give you more insight? http://www.packtpub.com/build-enterprise-mobile-web-application-using-rhomobile-beginners-guide/book

Comment: Titanium indeed does support Ruby. But not for mobile. This is for desktop only.